# Displaying a variable value in DWT, getting error says variable value has not been declared

Tags: 2011, dwt

I have a compound template that contains 2 C# TBB and 1 Dreamweaver template.
First TBB generates an xml from selected component, second TBB takes xpath and return a string value from the xml generated by first TBB and stores that string a in 'CusValue' variable.

I want to display the value of this 'CusValue'( which is 'project') in Dreamweaver template, I am using following syntax but i am getting variable "project" has not been declared.

#### @@CusValue@@

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. One of the TBBs return type was text/number instead of text/html. Once I made changed that it fixed the issue.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the question and answer what actually was going wrong, and what fixed it. What is the relationship between CusValue and project? Why did the error message refer to 'project' when you were trying to dereference CusValue?

Comment: CusValue is name of the item in package which is running in template builder and "project" is the resulting value of that item. I wanted to display the value of item in a Dreamweaver template. I used @@CusValue@@ but got error which i have mentioned, then i noticed my .net TBB has output type as "text/number" i changed that type to "text/html" abd it worked.

Comment: Why did that help?